# How to use BatchNormalization with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I am having trouble using Batch Normalization with tensorflow. I have build the following model:

```
def weight_variable(kernal_shape):
    weights = tf.get_variable(name='weights', shape=kernal_shape, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True,
                        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))
    return weights
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

# return 1 conv layer
def conv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, is_training, padding='SAME'):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)

    # Note that I used a stride of 2 on purpose in order not to use max pool layer.
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b
    conv = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, scale=True, is_training=is_training)

    activations = tf.nn.relu(conv)

    tf.summary.histogram("activations", activations)

    return activations

# return deconv layer
def deconv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, is_training, padding="SAME", activation='relu'):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram('biases', b)

    x_shape = tf.shape(x)
    # output shape: [batch_size, h * 2, w * 2, input_shape from w].
    out_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1] * 2, x_shape[2] * 2, w_shape[2]])
    # Note that I have used a stride of 2 since I used a stride of 2 in conv layer.

    conv_trans = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, out_shape, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b
    conv_trans = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv_trans, scale=True, is_training=is_training)

    if activation == 'relu':
        transposed_activations = tf.nn.relu(conv_trans)
    else:
        transposed_activations = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv_trans)

    tf.summary.histogram("transpose_activation", transposed_activations)
    return transposed_activations

def model(input):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv1 = conv_layer(input, [4, 4, 3, 32], [32], is_training=phase_train)  # image size: [56, 56]
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv2 = conv_layer(conv1, [4, 4, 32, 64], [64], is_training=phase_train)  # image size: [28, 28]
    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv3 = conv_layer(conv2, [4, 4, 64, 128], [128], is_training=phase_train)  # image size: [14, 14]
    with tf.variable_scope('conv4'):
        conv4 = conv_layer(conv3, [4, 4, 128, 256], [256], is_training=phase_train)  # image size: [7, 7]
        conv4_reshaped = tf.reshape(conv4, [batch_size * num_participants, 7 * 7 * 256], name='conv4_reshaped')

    w_c_mu = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7 * 7 * 256, latent_dim], stddev=0.1), name='weight_fc_mu')
    b_c_mu = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[latent_dim]), name='biases_fc_mu')
    w_c_sig = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7 * 7 * 256, latent_dim], stddev=0.1), name='weight_fc_sig')
    b_c_sig = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[latent_dim]), name='biases_fc_sig')
    epsilon = tf.random_normal([1, latent_dim])

    tf.summary.histogram('weights_c_mu', w_c_mu)
    tf.summary.histogram('biases_c_mu', b_c_mu)
    tf.summary.histogram('weights_c_sig', w_c_sig)
    tf.summary.histogram('biases_c_sig', b_c_sig)

    with tf.variable_scope('mu'):
        mu = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(conv4_reshaped, w_c_mu), b_c_mu)
        tf.summary.histogram('mu', mu)

    with tf.variable_scope('stddev'):
        stddev = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(conv4_reshaped, w_c_sig), b_c_sig)
        tf.summary.histogram('stddev', stddev)

    with tf.variable_scope('z'):
        # This formula was adopted from the following paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7979344
        latent_var = mu + tf.multiply(tf.sqrt(tf.exp(stddev)), epsilon)
        tf.summary.histogram('features_sig', stddev)

    with tf.variable_scope('GRU'):
        print(latent_var.get_shape().as_list())
        latent_var = tf.reshape(latent_var, shape=[int(batch_size / 100)* num_participants, time_steps, latent_dim])

        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(cell_size)   # state_size of cell_size.
        H, C = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, latent_var, dtype=tf.float32)  # H size: [batch_size * num_participants, SEQLEN, cell_size]
        H = tf.reshape(H, [batch_size * num_participants, cell_size])

    with tf.variable_scope('output'):
        # output layer.
        w_output = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([cell_size, 1], mean=0, stddev=0.01, dtype=tf.float32, name='w_output'))
        tf.summary.histogram('w_output', w_output)
        b_output = tf.get_variable('b_output', shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32,
                                   initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        predictions = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, w_output), b_output, name='softmax_output')
        tf.summary.histogram('output', predictions)

        var_list = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if 'GRU' in v.name]
        var_list.append([w_output, b_output])

    return predictions, var_list
```

In addition, I am restoring the model parameters as follows:

```
saver_torestore = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(events_path, sess.graph)
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    to_run_list = [merged, RMSE]

    # Initialize `iterator` with training data.
    sess.run(init_op)

    # Note that the last name "Graph_model" is the name of the saved checkpoints file => the ckpt is saved
    # under tensorboard_logs.
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(
        os.path.dirname(model_path))
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver_torestore.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print('checkpoints are saved!!!')
    else:
        print('No stored checkpoints')

    counter = 0
    for _ in range(num_epoch):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        print('epoch:', _)

        # This while loop will run indefinitly until the end of the first epoch
        while True:
            try:
                summary, loss_ = sess.run(to_run_list, feed_dict={phase_train: False})

                print('loss: ' + str(loss_))

                losses.append(loss_)
                counter += 1

                train_writer.add_summary(summary, counter)

            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('error, ignore ;) ')
                break

     print('average losses:', np.average(losses))
     train_writer.close()
```

I make sure that variables are saved. So I ran the following command:

```
def assign_values_to_batchNorm():
    vars = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if "BatchNorm" in v.name and "Adam" not in v.name]
    file_names = [(v.name[:-2].replace("/", "_") + ".txt") for v in vars]
    for var, file_name in zip(vars, file_names):
        lst = open(file_name).read().split(";")[:-1]
        print(lst)
        values = list(map(np.float32, lst))
        tf.assign(var, values)
```

*Please note that I have used this method in order to restore the values of moving mean and moving variance manually. But I got the same result.*

And I called the assign_values_to_batchNorm() under session. I got some values => It seems that the moving average, moving variance, gamma and betta are all saved.

Now Please note that I am working on windows 10, and I have tensorflow version 1.3.

So, whenever I run `summary, loss_ = sess.run(to_run_list, feed_dict={phase_train: True})` under the session as well, after initializing/restoring all variables, I got a RMSE of 0.022 which is the same error achieved at the end of training the model. Now, if I set `phase_train` to false, I got a `RMSE` of 0.038. Please note that I am just testing the network in the meanwhile. Therefore, even though I am using the training dataset for testing, but my purpose was just to test the behavior of the network while training/testing. So this is so weird I guess to me. And please note that the phase is placeholder. I have it in code as follows:

```
phase_train = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, name='phase')
```

In addition, here is the code snippet for the optimizer:

```
with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(RMSE)
```

**Main Problem:** RMSE = 0.038 when phase = False and 0.022 when phase = True.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I am still confused what your problem/expectation is. As far as I know, running a network with batch norm in train mode will update the running averages, so if you do that once then you probably will not get the same results anymore even if you feed in the same batch again in test mode right after.

Comment: Again, the problem is that I didn't use the testing dataset yet. I trained the network with the training dataset and then, run it once more with the training dataset while phase_train is False. And I got the RMSE reported above

Comment: `tf.assign(var, values)` returns an operation, which means that it does not really assign `values` to `var` unless you run this operation under a session. But I am not sure that is the problem because `saver_torestore.restore` should load all variables including moving_means and moving_vars by default. An another question about the RMSE you got: you test with all training data? you train with all training data each iteration instead of using a mini-batch?

Comment: Yes I test with all training data for 1 epoch using mini-batch. And I trained with all training data for 150 epoch using mini batch as well. Please note that the dataset consist of faces. So I'm not sure if working with faces makes any difference??

Comment: How many examples in a mini-batch when training and test? Is there any difference in pre-processing inputs between training phase and test phase? And why do you think RMSE=0.038 and RMSE=0.022 are very different? What results are you expecting? (They won't be the same, like the first comment here said, "you probably will not get the same results anymore".)

Comment: @Seven, Well I'm using the same number of examples in each batch in both training and testing. Additionally, I am trying to perform regression where my target falls between -1 and +1. Therefore, I want to be as close as possible to the target, which in my case, RMSE of 0.022 and 0.038 makes a difference. Hope this can answer your concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought that there might be a problem in using batch normalization layer. So I created a simple model and trained it on MNIST dataset. So we have 2 scenarios, in the first case, training the model with batch norm, 2nd, training it without batch norm.

Now, if we compared the testing result, with and without batch norm, we see that we get higher accuracy, or lower loss while using BN. Remember, the model that includes the BN, while testing the phase is set to false. Therefore, we can conclude that having a model with BN is better than that without BN.

Second, if we consider the model that was trained with batch normalization. Now, if we compare the loss on the test set (**while setting phase to True on one hand, and False on the other hand**), we conclude that we achieve better results when setting phase to True. Because, intuitively, using the statistics of the current batch are more accurate that the statistics of the training dataset.

In conclusion, my problem arises after training the model with batch normalization, and testing the model while setting phase to True, then, False. So, for sure we will get better loss (lower) while setting phase to true rather than false.

Answer (score 0):

## Restatement of the Question

It looks like your concern is this: you keep everything the same (training data, number of batches, number of epochs on your training data, initialization, etc.) except for the value of `phase_train`. When `phase_train=True`, doing the training yields a RMSE of 0.022 and when `phase_train=False`, doing the training yields a RMSE of 0.038, and you think regardless of the value of `phase_train`, the RMSE should be the same (either both 0.022 or 0.038). Please let me know if that's not what you meant.

## Answer to the Question

The answer here is that the RMSE is supposed to differ when `phase_train=True` versus when `phase_train=False`. Let's see why that's expected.

You set up your graph like this:

```
conv1 = conv_layer(input, [4, 4, 3, 32], [32], is_training=phase_train)
```

Then if we look at your the code in the `conv_layer(...)` function, you use the `is_training` variable like this:

```
conv = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, scale=True, is_training=is_training)
```

Now, let's look at the documentation for tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm):

> is_training: Whether or not the layer is in training mode. In training
>   mode it would accumulate the statistics of the moments into
>   moving_mean and moving_variance using an exponential moving average
>   with the given decay. When it is not in training mode then it would
>   use the values of the moving_mean and the moving_variance.

As can be seen from the documentation, `is_training=True` **causes different functionality** from when `is_training=False`. Specifically, when `is_training=True`, the normalization constant is calculated using a decay and when `is_training=False`, there is no decay. Your code does different stuff when you toggle the value of `is_training`, so your RMSE error is different.

If you run into more issues like this one, checking the Tensorflow documentation might help explain unexpected results. And also, it's not recommended to train your model with an `is_training` flag set to `False` somewhere.

## Why Use Decay When is_training=True?

You might be wondering why Tensorflow would be adding decay when `is_training=True`. The answer is that when you're training, the weights in your neural network are being **updated** to get better and better. That means the mean and variance on your earlier updates are very inaccurate and the mean and variance on your later updates are very accurate. Since earlier updates are inaccurate, you want to give them less say in how the neural network weights should be updated, so you decay by 0.999 on every subsequent update.

For example, when `is_training=True`, the mean and variance from your first update to the weights is `0.999^10000 ~ 0.000045` as significant as the mean and variance on your 10,000th update. This makes sense because on your first update, your weights are essentially random, and definitely do not produce a mean and variance as meaningful as the mean and variance on the 10000th update.

When `is_training=False`, that means you're telling Tensorflow you've already learned the appropriate weights in your neural network. You're telling Tensorflow that you've already trained everything, the weights are meaningful, and the mean and variance you get in your batch norm are meaningful. So, there's no need to decay anything.

This explanation would be consistent with your RMSE error. If you train with `is_training=False`, you are being inefficient by giving more significance to the random weights you initialized your neural network with, so your final model won't be as good. And as you observed, your RMSE error from the `is_training=False` run is higher than your RMSE error from the `is_training=True` run.

Comment: So you mean I should set the decay to a smaller value when `is_training=False`? If yes, is there any ideal value? Thank you for your help

Comment: As the documentation said, whenever `is_training=False`, it ignores the decay. There's no point in using a decay when `is_training=False`. Decay is only relevant when `is_training=True`. Even if you set decay to a smaller value, it'll still be ignored if `is_training=False`.

Comment: so I agree with you. But the problem is that, even after initializing the model, using `sess.run(init_op)`, I am restoring the whole graph using `saver_torestore.restore`. Hence, I am not initializing randomly as you have mentioned. Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Thank you.

Comment: Let's say you delete all your checkpoints. Then what checkpoint can you restore from? Even if you restore from a checkpoint, at the very beginning, you had no checkpoints, so you had to have initialized randomly. You have `initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02)` in your code for the weight initialization. Also, checkpoints are like "backups" in case you over-train or your code crashes. You shouldn't be reinitializing from a checkpoint on every training iteration. Your graph can save the state as it runs. Can you post your code that runs the various iterations of the graph?

Comment: Okay please see the edited code above under `tf.Session() as sess:`

Comment: In your edited code, you initialize at the beginning with a checkpoint if it exists. Then you train: `while True: ... summary, loss_ = sess.run(...)`. Every iteration in the while loop, your adam optimizer will backpropagate and slightly modify the neural network weights. And if you have `is_training=True` the backprop will consider the decayed means and variances in the batch norm. If you have `is_training=False`, the backprop will consider the normal mean and variance. Again, your code works differently based on the setting of `is_training`.

Comment: And as the Tensorflow documentation said, there is *no* way to get the `is_training=True` RMSE error with the `is_training=False` RMSE error in your situation because they don't train in the same manner.

Comment: I guess this is not true. To do back propagation and change the weights, you have to run the optimizer operation, i.e., `sess.run(optimizer)` and this is not happening in my case. Therefore, I'm just propagating the batch of images and looking at the RMSE. Second, to comment on your previous comment, please note that when restoring the variables, whatever values the weights takes at the beginning will be replaced. To illustrate that, I tried running the model without the `sess.run(init_op)` and I got the same answer. So still I guess you didn't figure out the mistake. Thank you again!!

Comment: I think we've gotten a bit off track. When I saw "epochs" I assumed you were training your data. I guess that wasn't quite right: you're just computing the same RMSE over and over again... which was not intuitive for me. So forget about how you're running the graph. This is still due to the decay factor. In the `is_training=True` mode when you run RMSE, which triggers the batch_norm, you're going to multiply the moving statistics by 0.99. In the `is_training=False` mode you don't multiply by 0.99. You are still doing different things when you toggle `is_training`.

Comment: I think this is getting into a very long discussion now. I'll leave at this: You toggle `is_training` and the tensorflow documentation tells us that changes the behavior. I hope you resolve your issue.